# Is it possible to prevent disk replacement in a laptop so it cannot be used after theft?

Tags: boot, laptop, security, uefi

I have an ASUS ROG Zephyrus G14 laptop and want to make it impossible (or at least very difficult) for someone except me to use my laptop. I already have the password in Windows 10 and the admin password in bios, disabled USB storage devices in BIOS. But if I understand correctly, a thief can simply replace my SSD with another which has an installed system and then use my laptop. Is there a relatively easy way to prevent it?

I could set the user password in BIOS too (that would solve the problem, a thief wouldn't be able to turn on the computer), but I don't want it, because I have to enter the password every time I turn the laptop on.

Also, I could enable secure boot, but I am not sure if it would help to achieve my goal. Purpose of secure boot is to resist attacks and infection from malware. Would it prevent disk replacement?

Comment: You state, “But if I understand correctly, a thief can simply replace my SSD with another which has an installed system and then use my laptop. Is there a relatively easy way to prevent it?” What is the logic here? Let’s say someone steals your laptop, what benefit do _you_ gain by preventing the laptop being used by a thief? What do you think the chances are of the thief coming back to you and saying “You win! I couldn’t add a new storage device. You deserve this back.” The biggest concern in device theft is data; that is irreplaceable. A laptop and storage costs money but is easily replaced.

Comment: Set a BIOS Password, so its impossible for the thief to change the boot order and install a new OS. (Not sure what happens when you reset the BIOS)

Comment: Setting up BIOS password does nothing. They don't even need cracking, one single google search gives immediately multiple options how to clear, change or bypass it.

Comment: Fortunately, BIOS password is not always easy to bypass. I was looking for information about the possibility of bypass the BIOS password on ASUS G14 and didn't find anything. I think it depends on the model and the newer the computer, the better protected its BIOS.

Comment: Physical access is root access. period. Encryption can help protect data, but at the hardware level, only sophisticated hardware could help with theft scenarios when the hardware itself is the goal of the attack. even technologies like CompuTrace's LoJack can be bypassed by a mildly skilled theif. https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000156181/computrace-lojack-for-laptops-frequently-asked-questions-faq

Comment: Secure Boot using a custom certificate authority would certainly do the trick. Whether it's feasible (you'd have to un-trust all standard CAs and sign your boot files), who knows.

Answer (score 4):

Disks and RAM sticks are usually intended to be user-replaceable parts. There's really no way to conveniently secure them so that they couldn't be replaced.

You could replace the standard philips screws with tamper-proof ones, but those can still be opened with the appropriate tool or simply drilled out. You could glue the drive slot's access cover or even glue the drive to its place, but that also prevents you from replacing it if it fails. And a thief can just break the cover. You can lock it in a steel box with seven keys, and the thief can steal the entire box.

Security is always a balancing game. The more difficult you make it for someone else to use your system, the more difficult you make it for yourself. Any method to secure the system can be overriden with time and dedication.

There's one way to secure your laptop, the same you use for every other thing you own: *always know where it is*.

**Giacomo1968**'s comment is very much on point. There are solutions for tracking stolen laptops. Some manufacturers even include a solution to the purchase price of the laptop; at least for a limited time. However those also are only effective for a limited time.

So taking care that your personal data doesn't get into wrong hands is more important than worrying about the hardware. Three basic things:

1. ***Backup your data regularly***, at least in a separate external drive, but preferably in 2 separate locations - backups can also fail. A cloud solution is again useful.
2. Never store any critical information on the laptop drive alone, always keep an up-to-date copy on a separate USB stick, cloud storage etc. so that in case of theft (or a HW failure) it's always available for you
3. Encrypt the drive. Even if your device is stolen, an encrypted drive is practically impossible to access.

Comment: While I generally agree with this answer, as you can [read in my comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1678183/is-it-possible-to-prevent-disk-replacement-in-a-laptop#comment2575441_1678183) the whole premise of this question is odd: My $1,500 laptop has been stolen and I do not want the thief to use it. I mean if the device is stolen, who cares? The thief will never return it. It is gone whether it is usable or not. The $1,500 is gone. The only concern should ever be is the user data on the laptop safe. A $1,500 laptop with personal data on it becomes very valuable in the wrong hands.

Comment: What can I do but agree? :-D

Comment: I totally agree with you about the importance of data protection. 

I already make backups and use encryption.

Comment: That's about as secure as you can get then :-)

Answer (score 0):

### If your device is stolen, it is stolen.

#### How it is used afterwards is really an odd concern since the laptop is gone and never coming back.

Straight at the top: User replaceable hardware and external drive access can be locked down to a point, but as you state:

> “I could set the user password in BIOS too (that would solve the problem, a thief wouldn’t be able to turn on the computer), but I don’t want it, because I have to enter the password every time I turn the laptop on.”

Correct. Your own life will be made harder by doing this. And it will not prevent the actual issue: Your device being stolen.

But more to the point, you state:

> “But if I understand correctly, a thief can simply replace my SSD with another which has an installed system and then use my laptop. Is there a relatively easy way to prevent it?”

What is the logic here? Let’s say someone steals your laptop, what benefit do you gain by preventing the laptop being used by a thief? What do you think the chances are of the thief coming back to you and saying:

> “You win! I couldn’t add a new storage device. You deserve this back.”

The biggest concern in device theft is data; that is irreplaceable. A laptop and storage costs money but is easily replaced. An ASUS ROG Zephyrus G14 laptop costs around $1,500. You will definitely never recover that $1,500 but a $1,500 laptop with personal data on it becomes very valuable in the wrong hands.

Data security should always be your concern: Not whether the laptop is used by the thief.

Comment: You are right, the thief would not return the laptop even if he couldn't use it. I assumed that such an answer would appear. 

But:

1. If a theft happens then I would be glad that the crook at least would not benefit from his crime. It's about psyhology :)
2. If I would lost the laptop (that's unlikely, but there is possibility) the finder would be encourage to return the laptop for reward rather than use/sell it.

My data is already protected, I make backups and use encryption.